# The case when the copy-constructor implicitly defined as deleted

Tags: c++, constructor

The section `N3797::12.8/11 [class.copy]` says:

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public
>   member of its class. A defaulted copy/ move constructor for a class X
>   is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> [...]
>
> — a non-static data
>   member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved
>   because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding
>   constructor, results in an ambiguity *or a function that is deleted or*
>   *inaccessible from the defaulted constructor*

The first case about the ambiguity of corresponding copy/move constructor is quite clear. We can write the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(){ }
    A(volatile A&){ }
    A(const A&, int a = 6){ }
};

struct U
{
    U(){ };
    A a;
};

U u;

U t = u;

int main(){ }
```

to reflect that. But what about *or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor*? What's that got with a function inaccessible from the default constructor? Could you provide an example reflecting that?

Comment: It says *defaulted constructor*, not "default constructor" - this is referring to the defaulted copy/move constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put:

```
struct M { M(M const&) =delete; };
struct X { X(X const&) =default; M m; }; // X(X const&) is actually deleted!
```

Implicitly-declared functions are also considered "defaulted" ([dcl.fct.def.default] / 5); a more familiar pre-C++11 example might be something like:

```
struct M { protected: M(M const&); };
struct X { M m; }; // X's implicit copy constructor is deleted!
```

Note that if you explicitly default the function *after* it has been declared, the program is ill-formed if the function would be implicitly deleted ([dcl.fct.def.default] / 5):

```
struct M { M(M const&) =delete; };
struct X { X(X const&); M m; };

X::X(X const&) =default; // Not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0):

> a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because *overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function* that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor

The wording is perhaps slightly contrived, for conciseness most certainly. The idea, as emphasised in the above, is that the function in question **is** the `M` *copy constructor* being overloaded in way which renders it inaccessible. So having a member of class `M` whose copy constructor is made `protected` for instance would `delete` the copy constructor of `X`. Likewise, simply deleting the copy constructor of `M` would have the same result.